# Set minimum tick interval in altair

Tags: altair

How can I set the minimum tick interval in altair (using version 5.1.1 in this example)?

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
    'b': [1.4, 2.3, 2.1, 4.6, 4.0, 2.7, 0.9, 4.3, 2.6]
})

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='a',
    y=alt.Y('b', axis=alt.Axis(tickMinStep=1))
)
```

Code slightly adapted from [the Altair gallery](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/simple_bar_chart.html)

My understanding was, that setting the `tickMinStep` to 1 creates always integer numbers on the y axis (i.e.: 1, 2, 3, ...).

However, the output of the plot shows decimal values on the y axis as well:

[image]

Is my understanding of the parameter `tickMinStep` wrong? And how can I set the minimum distance to 1 (or only show integer values on the y axis)?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a bug in Vega-Lite and will be resolved once this issue is fixed https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/9034